# Generating DXL documentation using Doxygen : if is shown as a function

Tags: doxygen, ibm-doors

I am trying to generate some DXL documentation usings Doxygen , but the results are often not correct , DXL is used as a scripting language and that has a C/C++ like syntax with some changes , like for example i can ignor using the Semicolons , What should i do to correct this problem ? 
which creates some problems while generating the documentation, here is an example of my dxl code database :

```
string replace (string sSource, string sSearch, string sReplace) {
int iLen = length sSource
if (iLen == 0) return ""

int iLenSearch = length(sSearch)

if (iLenSearch == 0) { 

    return "" 
}
char firstChar = sSearch[0]

Buffer s = create() 
int pos = 0, d1,d2;    
int i

while (pos < iLen) { 
    char ch = sSource[pos]; 
    bool found = true

    if (ch != firstChar) {pos ++; s+= ch; continue}
    for (i = 1; i < iLenSearch; i++) {
       if (sSource[pos+i] != sSearch[i]) { found = false; break }
    }
    if (!found) {pos++; s+= ch; continue}
    s += sReplace
    pos += iLenSearch
}

string result = stringOf s
delete s
return result   }
```

as i said the main difference with C and that may cause doxygen to interpret this code incorrectly is that in DXL , we dont have to use ";" .

thanks in advance

Comment: So doxygen doesn't support DXL, are you just telling it to parse it as C?
Also would be more useful if you provided an example of code that causes a problem, and what the problem is.

Comment: @ArturKink i modified my post

Answer (score 0):

You must do three things to apply Doxygen successfully on DXL scripts:

1.) In Doxygen-GUI, 'Wizard' tab, section 'Mode' choose 'Optimize for C or PHP'

2.) The DXL code must be C-confom, i.e. each statement ends with a semicolon ';'

3.) In tab 'Expert' set language mapping for DXL and INC files in section 'Project' under 'EXTENSION_MAPPING':
      dxl=C 
      inc=C

This all tells Doxygen to treat DXL scripts as C code.

Answer (score 0):

Further, for DOORS to recognize a DXL file documented for DoxyGen as valid and bind it to a menu item, it must comply with certain header structure, consisting of single line and multi-line comment, e.g.

```
// <dxl-file>
/**
 * @file <dxl-file>
 * @copyright (c) ...
 * @author Th. Grosser
 * @date 01 Dec 2017
 * @brief ...
 */
```